# Redux Observable: Fire same epic for multiple actions

Tags: redux-observable

I want to fire the same contents of my epic in response to several actions.
Something like this:

```
export default function uploadImage(action$, store) {
  return action$.ofType([
      'UPDATE_IMAGE,
      'UPDATE_INTERESTS',
      'UPDATE_LANGUAGE',
      ...
    ])
    .switchMap(action => {
      Api.updateUser();
    })
};
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're correct in your self-answer, `ofType` accepts an arbitrary number of types as arguments.

This isn't currently documented because in practice we've found almost always it's a sign of an anti-pattern--not always, but it's highly suspicious.

Until we have solid guidance on when it's good or bad, we want to continue to discourage it's use as a general rule, but certainly only you can be the judge of whether it's appropriate or not.

Comment: was the "solid guidance" ever documented? Thanks!

Comment: Nope. From what I've seen, there are some cases where it makes sense but other cases where it's probably a sign of doing something weird. Difficult to give general guidance.

Comment: @jayphelps could you please provide some insights on why this is an anti-pattern?

Comment: @jbmusso Because usually (but not always) it's a sign your epic is doing too many things or your actions are effectively duplicates. An example of an exception to this is an epic which listens for multiple actions and then logs them for insight purposes, without really introspecting the contents of the action.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the docs it seems to take an variable amount of arguments: https://github.com/redux-observable/redux-observable/blob/fd393a1adf359381c98ca494bc5dc2cac80f6d07/src/ActionsObservable.js#L26